# How to store log of all changes to Eloquent model in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel

I want to store changes to `all` fields in Eloquent model into database.

I can do it using `created` and `updated` events but there is a problem with `multiple` foreign relations (described as separate tables).

Example:

```
User
    login
    Roles -> hasMany
```

When I update login field it is easy to write old and new value into database, but when I update Roles relation nothing happens.

How can I track all foreign relations (like hasMany, hasManyThrough, ManyToMany)?

Comment: You want to store the actual changes like a versioning, or just the time a field changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no embedded and simple method to do it.
Eloquent doesn't provide any method to implement observers on related models by design. Many proposal in this way have been rejected by Taylor ([just one example](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2303)).

The only thing you can do, is to create your own methods to do it.
You have many possibilities, here are some of them in order of complexity (some of them are "dirty" :-)

- add a `created` and `updated` observer on each related model
- override the `save()` or create your own `saveAndFire()` method on your eloquent instances, and from that method retrieve the parent and call its log methods before saving. (this is a little bit "dirty" imho)
- encapsulate all your persistence layer and fire events yourself on saving objects (look at the repository pattern, for example)

Answer (score 3):

Owen-it has a very nice Library called [laravel-auditing](https://github.com/owen-it/laravel-auditing), which keeps an easy to query list of all changes that are made to a model, and I think it does quite an awesome piece of work. Have used it and it is worth it to try out.